# Sub-object in Vue property is losing methods from prototype

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue to display (among other things) an hexagonal grid.
I'm using the [Honeycomb](https://github.com/flauwekeul/honeycomb) lib to represent it in memory. It provides a `Grid` object that contains the actual data and many methods to manipulate it (including all methods from `Array` type for convenience).

I tried passing it as a property to my Vue component

```
@Component
export default class TileMap extends Vue {
@Prop() private grid!: Grid;
```

but all methods are lost in my Vue component

- they are in the prototype when creating the `Grid` object
- they are **not** in the prototype when using the `Grid` property in my component

Is it expected?
Should I avoid properties for objects with properties?

Comment: It's unclear how you use it and how did you make a conclusion that they are not in prototype. Please, provide clear problem statement https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that explains your case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately

> The object must be plain: native objects such as browser API objects
> and prototype properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data
> should just be data - it is not recommended to observe objects with
> their own stateful behavior.

[source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

I don't see any good workaround for this scenario.

Storing stuff in window object?

Wrap grid logic in some service with internal state?

**Or wrap grid in a function and then pass it to child as prop?**

The last one works surprisingly

```js
import { defineGrid, Grid, GridFactory } from 'honeycomb-grid'
import Test from './Test.vue'
import { Vue, Component, Prop, Provide, ProvideReactive } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
    components : { Test }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
    @Provide() private gridFunc: () => Grid = null;

    mounted() {
        const grid = defineGrid().rectangle({ width: 4, height: 4 });
        this.gridFunc = () => grid;
    }
}
```

```js
import { defineGrid, Grid, GridFactory } from 'honeycomb-grid'
import { Vue, Component, ProvideReactive, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class Test extends Vue {
    @Prop() private gridFunc!: () => Grid<any>;
    
    @Watch('gridFunc')
    onGridChange(val: string, oldVal: string) {
        console.log(this.gridFunc());
    }
}
```